# Where to store service certificates and their associated private key?

Tags: ssl, ssl-certificate, certificate

I created a program that gets the Let’s Encrypt certificates for my services (web sites, dovecot and smtp).

I previously stored these service certificates in /etc/ssl/certs (I’m on Debian), and just found that this is a bad idea. This directory is for root certificates.

Let’s Encrypt stores certificates and private keys in a directory named /etc/letsencrypt/live. These are renewed every two to three months.

Is it a good idea to store such type of files in a sub-directory of /etc ? Shouldn’t they be stored in /var since they are modifying data ? /var/local perhaps ?

Answer (score 1):

Reading [this explanation on /var/lib](https://refspecs.linuxfoundation.org/FHS_3.0/fhs/ch05s08.html) and [this answer](https://superuser.com/a/20688/15894) was very helpful.

It appears that the right place to store certificates and private keys generated and renewed by my program is in `/var/lib/<program-name>` with sub-directories `certs` and `private`.